# how to get a filename in HTML and use it in D3.js (javascript)?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I've written a d3 script that plots some data and in which the path to the input file is hard coded.

I'd like to be able to select the file by browsing on my computer and then passing it to the script.

```
<body>

<!--locally browse to get the filename-->
<input type="file" id="input">

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.js"></script>
<script> 

// Get the data
d3.tsv("#input", function(error, data) {
data.forEach(function(d) {
d.date = parseDate(d.date);
d.close = +d.close;
});

// then the code that plots etc....
</script>


</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Create the input select button and register it to a file select handler function:

```
var input = d3.select("body").append("input")
        .attr("type","file")
        .on("change", handleFileSelect)
```

2) The file select handler will register a new function with the fileHandler as input on the onload callback:

```
// Single file handler
function handleFileSelect() {
    // Check for the various File API support.
    if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
    // Great success! All the File APIs are supported.
    } else {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
    }

    var f = event.target.files[0]; // FileList object
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(event) {
        load_d3(event.target.result)
    };
    // Read in the file as a data URL.
    reader.readAsDataURL(f);
}
```

3) Crete a function with a fileHandler as input, that calls your D3 code (d3.json in this example. You can adapt it for tsv)

```
function load_d3(fileHandler) {
    d3.json(fileHandler, function(error, root) {
        //do stuff
    };
};
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Subscribe to input file change event. Then use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) to get content of selected file, then parse it using [d3.tsv.parse](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/CSV#tsv_parse)

Comment: Could you please elaborate more?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [d3.csvParse](https://github.com/d3/d3-dsv) to parse the result after reading file. Here's my working code:

```
<input type="file" id="input" onchange="handleFiles">

<script>
const inputElement = document.getElementById("input");
inputElement.addEventListener("change", handleFiles, false);

function handleFiles() {
    const fileList = this.files; /* now you can work with the file list */
    var file = fileList[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) {
        // The file's text will be printed here
        console.log(e.target.result);
        console.log(d3.csvParse(e.target.result));
    };
    reader.readAsText(file);
}
```